# How to properly escape the characters in this regex construction

Tags: javascript

I am building a naive `rstrip` function. And it works properly like this when I hardcode the actual characters:

```js
const rstrip = (s, chars) => s.replace(/[r!]+$/g, "");
console.log(rstrip("Hello!!!!r", '!r'))
```

However, if I try and use the `chars` variable, I have trouble escaping it:

```js
const rstrip = (s, chars) => s.replace(/[chars]+$/g, "");
console.log(rstrip("Hello!!!!r", '!r'))
```

What would be the proper way to 'escape' the variable so that the value `!r` replaces the `chars` variable in the `replace` method?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be about escaping, it's about how to substitute a variable in a regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const rstrip = (s, chars) => s.replace(new RegExp(`[${chars}]+$`, 'g'), "");
console.log(rstrip("Hello!!!!r", '!r'))
```

Comment: This won't work properly if `chars` contains `]`, `-` because they have special meaning inside `[]`